# How to split pandas column in 2 with varying pattern

Tags: pandas, design-patterns, split

I have fetched dataframe from site with selenium and one of a columns in a table has a name and serial number in one cell. In frontend it looks fine cause serial number is put in  but when i fetch it into pandas dataframe it fetching it in 1 cell, pattern of serial number is vary.
The pattern can look like `b05/124125` or either `f07/d05/f95/10581`

I've been searching for some implementation in internet and looks like "column.str.split()" doesnt feet the situation i have.

for example i have:

```
name                                 status
Looking Glassmo02/12581              active
Going Wildfo06/86351                 inactive
"Fine Lads"ni29/ao05/io85/02350      awaiting verification
Some Other Nameio95/fo94/6841        active
```

I want to have

```
name              serial                  status
Looking Glass     mo02/12581              active
Going Wild        fo06/86351              inactive    
"Fine Lads"       ni29/ao05/io85/02350    awaiting verification
Some Other Name   io95/fo94/6841          active
```

I getting table from html file with pd.read_excel

Comment: please provide a clear example of your input DataFrame and the matching expected output